# Calculate Y-axis breaks

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

We have a UI requirement to introduce a break in the graph when the first value on the y-axis is not 0. Naturally I started off with setting the yAxis min value to 0 and I decided to introduce a break in the y-axis. Here is the relevant options

```
yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 2,
    min: 0,
    breaks: [
      {
        from: 0,
        to: 100
      }
    ]
  }

With data of 

[180, 220, 450, 562]
```

Now this works great when the data we are using is static but obviously in our case it is not. The data we are getting back is from another service and varies a lot.

Is it possible to get a minimum value of the yaxis that is calculated by highcharts?

I can introduce a break from 0 to that calculated min value?

You guys can see what I have worked on so far:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y-axis-line-break-c61jj?file=/demo.jsx:1470-1490)

I am mainly doing this because we have a requirement to add the swigly as in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all - it seems that you missed importing the `broken-axis` module.

```
import HighchartsBrokenAxis from "highcharts/modules/broken-axis";

HighchartsBrokenAxis(Highcharts);
```

Next, I want to suggest another solution - use the `render` callback to check the `yAxis.minData` and do an update on the yAxis.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    render() {
      const chart = this,
        yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
        dataMin = yAxis.dataMin;

      if (chartForRender) {
        chartForRender = false;
        yAxis.update({
          breaks: [
            {
              from: 1,
              to: dataMin
            }
          ]
        });
      }
      chartForRender = true;
    }
  }
},
```

Notice that I used the `chartForRender` flag to be sure that the update call will be triggered only once.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jr5bjw?file=index.js

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update